# I am not able to parse the json array as I am getting the json ex

Tags: android, arrays, json

I am trying to parse a `Json Array` using the following code.

My `URL` is `http://166.62.17.208/json_preferencess.aspx`

I am getting the following errors:

`Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: No value for id`

I have displayed the `result` as follows:

`[{"items":[{"id":"11","Item_Id":"123","Item_Name":"Chicken Cream /* and the remaining  objects of the array*/`

And I get the jArray as follows:

`[{"questions":[{"q_id":"1","q_question":"How would you rate our Menu /* and the remaining  objects of the array*/`

I am getting the length of the jArray as 1 even though the length is more than one.

I have posted my codes below, please guide me step by step as I am very new to json.

```
    String result = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://166.62.17.208/json_preferencess.aspx");

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 

            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

            Log.e("log_tag", "connection success "+"nameValuePairs");

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());


    }
    try
    {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,HTTP.UTF_8),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");

            }
            is.close();

            result=sb.toString();
          Log.e("log_tag", "result "+result.toString());
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
           Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());


    }
    try
    {
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        Log.w("Lenghsssssss",""+jArray);
          String s="",s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7,s8,s9;
          Log.w("Lengh",""+jArray.length());
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){


                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                  s=json_data.getString("id");

                   Log.e("taskid from server","s");

            }



    }
    catch(JSONException e)
    {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());

    }
```

Comment: You have to make an "items" array before you can loop through it and retrieve "id". What is jArray.length() now?

Comment: Can you please post some code..so that I can understand a bit better?jArray.length() is equal to 1.

Comment: Something like `JSONArray items = jArray.getJSONArray("items");`. ?

Comment: It appears that your JSON contains an array which contains a single object in turn contains an array with the given key. You will need to dig down through these layers to obtain the data you want.

Comment: @greenapps  I tried that but it still gives me errors

Answer (score 1):

```
[ // Json Array
    { // Json Object
        "items": [// Josn Array
            {
                "id": "11",
```

Try like this

```
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        String s="",s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7,s8,s9;
        Log.w("Lengh",""+jArray.length());
        for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
            JSONArray newarr = jArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("items");
            for(int j= 0; j<newarr.length();j++){
                JSONObject json_data = newarr.getJSONObject(i);
                s=json_data.getString("id");
                System.out.println("Id is: "+ s);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I am not getting any errors now but the length of the array is still one and I am getting only one value.